# How can I change the title text of my website on a GitHub Pages website?

Tags: github, github-pages

I have a GitHub Pages website and I don't know how to change the title text. Not the title text shown on the website, the little text next to the favicon on a webpage. I have attached a screenshot for you guys to view.

I have tried using the title thing in HTML but it ends up getting thrown at the main-content thing when I inspect element it and it gets ignored and uses its own custom title that I can't change.

[This is the title that I am talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xEiV.png)

[I don't want this title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2Eoj.png)

[This is the title I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TP53H.png)

[And this is what the title actually becomes, the wrong title.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuVNO.png)

Any way to do this?

Comment: That isn't it! I showed it in my post

Comment: Please post examples of what you have already tried and explain what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `<title> text here </title>`

Comment: Do I have to make a html file? I am currently using index.md and _config.yml